# If I select a single vertex and drag, the whole object stretches out instead of just the vertex selected

Tags: modeling

I subdivided the cube and changed to edit mode so I can edit the vertex. The problem is if I select a single vertex and drag, the whole object stretches out instead of just the vertex selected. The proportional editing if off, so I don't know what is wrong cause I am new to blender.

Comment: did you subdivide with the subsurf modifier per chance?

Comment: could you please show some pictures?

Answer (score 0):

You can subdivide and It'll add another geometry and then when u select the object from the subdivision you can drag it and it'll stretch out from the subdivision only.
You can add subdivision by pressing "R" and you can scroll up or down in order to increase the no. of subdivision.And then right click if u want it to stay on center.
Thank you hope it'll help